# AWS Lambda Handler extend S3event

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda

I have the following pipeline:

A file is uploaded to S3, it triggers a Lambda (Let's call it L1) which runs and does some processing.

So at the moment, my entry point looks like this:

```
public Response handleRequest(S3Event event, Context context) {
  ....
}
```

Now, a S3Event JSON looks like this:

```
        {
            "Records": [
                {
                    "awsRegion": "xxxxx",
                    "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
                    "eventSource": "aws:s3",
                    "eventTime": "2017-09-12T09:27:59.471Z",
                    "eventVersion": "2.0",
                    "requestParameters": {
                        "sourceIPAddress": "xxxxxx"
                    },
                    "responseElements": {
                        "x-amz-id-2": "xxxxxx",
                        "x-amz-request-id": "xxxx"
                    },
                    "s3": {
                        "configurationId": "xxxxxx1",
                        "bucket": {
                            "name": "xxxxx",
                            "ownerIdentity": {
                                "principalId": "xxxxx"
                            },
                            "arn": "xxx"
                        },
                        "object": {
                            "key": "xxx",
                            "size": xxx,
                            "eTag": "xxxx",
                            "versionId": null,
                            "sequencer": "xxx",
                            "urlDecodedKey": "xxx"
                        },
                        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0"
                    },
                    "userIdentity": {
                        "principalId": "xxxx"
                    }
                }
            ],
        }
```

If you pass this JSON in the "Test" section, it will succeed.

Now, to the point: I wish to add information to this JSON, something that would look like this:

```
        {
            "Records": [
                {
                    "awsRegion": "xxxxx",
                    "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
                    "eventSource": "aws:s3",
                    "eventTime": "2017-09-12T09:27:59.471Z",
                    "eventVersion": "2.0",
                    "requestParameters": {
                        "sourceIPAddress": "xxxxxx"
                    },
                    "responseElements": {
                        "x-amz-id-2": "xxxxxx",
                        "x-amz-request-id": "xxxx"
                    },
                    "s3": {
                        "configurationId": "xxxxxx1",
                        "bucket": {
                            "name": "xxxxx",
                            "ownerIdentity": {
                                "principalId": "xxxxx"
                            },
                            "arn": "xxx"
                        },
                        "object": {
                            "key": "xxx",
                            "size": xxx,
                            "eTag": "xxxx",
                            "versionId": null,
                            "sequencer": "xxx",
                            "urlDecodedKey": "xxx"
                        },
                        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0"
                    },
                    "userIdentity": {
                        "principalId": "xxxx"
                    }
                }
            ],

             "MyErrorMessage":
                {
                "EnvelopeErrors": [
                    {
                        "EnvelopeErrorTrace": "stackTrace",
                        "EnvelopeErrorPositions": 1,
                        "EnvelopeErrorLength": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "EnvelopeErrorTrace": "SecondTrace",
                        "EnvelopeErrorPositions": 3,
                        "EnvelopeErrorLength": 4
                    }
                ],
                }
        }
```

Notice is the S3Event JSon but with a bit more data.

My question problem is the following: I want to have a custom input that also works when a pure S3Event is called.

```
 public Response handleRequest(MyS3Event event, Context context) {
    ....
 }
```

However, I have not been able to achieve this.

I have tried a custom POJO but it does not work when I upload to S3 a file.
I tried to extend the S3EventNotification class (from which S3Event extends), but again with no success.

Is it possible what I am trying to do?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by adding more data to s3 event json?
Ideally when you work in event driven environment event attributes are constant as the attributes deal with very specific data triggering the event,

Comment: @Suyash What I am trying to do is add information to the original event so my Lambda re-process the original file, but not completely but only parts of it using the additional information.

Comment: Do you mean, once your lambda received S3Event, you want to modify it and same lambda should again process it but this time with modified data?

Comment: @Suyash Not exactly. A S3Event launches a Lambda. It stores information of failed "parts" plus the received event. Therefore, a second lambda has to be launched (with the same exact code) and it only reprocesses the failed parts.

Comment: So you want to launch one lambda from other which will store data on s3 bucket?

Comment: Again, no. One Lambda is launched with because of an S3 event. The second time is launched, it's by manually passing the JSON I described.

Comment: I believe it is not possible. Also, what you are trying to achieve needs to be redesigned. It is not recommended to modify event json manually.

Comment: @Alessandroempire Is this going to be recursive? Will the second invocation lead to a third and so on?

Comment: @dashmug Yes, it is a possibility. At the moment, no, because it is being invoked manually. But the idea is that it is invoked by another lambda that is launched using a scheduled event.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to have your Lambda (L1) call itself (asynchronously) by sending it the new, modified event similar to how recursive functions work.

Just be very careful though. You have to put a limit as to how deep you want to keep recursing. You don't want to end up with infinite calls. I am not sure if AWS guards against this.

Answer (score 0):

In the AWS SDK Lambda has an [invoke method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property):

> Invokes a specific Lambda function. For an example, see [Create the Lambda Function and Test It Manually.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-dynamodb-create-function.html#with-dbb-invoke-manually)
>
> If you are using the versioning feature, you can invoke the specific
>   function version by providing function version or alias name that is
>   pointing to the function version using the Qualifier parameter in the
>   request. If you don't provide the Qualifier parameter, the $LATEST
>   version of the Lambda function is invoked. Invocations occur at least
>   once in response to an event and functions must be idempotent to
>   handle this. For information about the versioning feature, see [AWS Lambda Function Versioning and Aliases](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-aliases.html).
>
> This operation requires permission for the lambda:InvokeFunction
>   action.

```
var params = {
  FunctionName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  ClientContext: 'STRING_VALUE',
  InvocationType: Event | RequestResponse | DryRun,
  LogType: None | Tail,
  Payload: new Buffer('...') || 'STRING_VALUE',
  Qualifier: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

One of the `params` you send a `Payload` which is the `event` the invoked function receives so you can send your `MyErrorMessage` in/as this payload to get the desired result.